# Pre-populate Slug / Permalink with URL

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

I would like to not only pre-populate the title, tags, and categories, but would also like to pre-populate the slug / permalink as well.

Can I do this and if so how?

**Here's my functions.php code:**

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'myplugin_post_new' );
function myplugin_post_new(){
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'myplugin_wp_insert_post_default' );
}
function myplugin_wp_insert_post_default( $post_id ){
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $_REQUEST['tags']);
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $_REQUEST['cat']);
}
```

If I go to **.../post-new.php?post_title=testing&content=testing2&tags=2014&cat=1**, I get my title, content, tag, and category pre-populated. Only missing the slug/permalink.

Currently, I'm not wanting to use the XML-RPC method...

**What I would like to do:**

I would like to generate a page dynamically from a user's response in a form. The user would then be presented an editor where they can make final edits before publishing.

Comment: Your new post is an "auto-draft". The permalink will not be stable until the post is published, so even if you pre-populated it you couldn't really count on it staying the same. [Perhaps you could explain what you are needing to accomplish instead of focusing on the details of what you think you need to _do_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that in auto-draft - providing the permalink is not possible. I also looked at following up with some form of a **...post.php?post=1&action=edit&slug=testing** link, but doesn't look to be supported there either...

As for what I'm needing to accomplish, I'll edit the question and add that...